# Password prompt frozen

Tags: password, keyrings

When I switch on my laptop, this prompt appears:
[image: Password prompt]

I can not however type anything. After three minutes it lets me type in the problem.

Why is this happening? May it be hardware related?

- [Hardware details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stvow.png)
- [Hardware list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYMYj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled autologin. Because of that, the keyring is not automatically unlocked, so the password is asked for a process that needs a key. In your case, that happens to be a process that is automatically launched when you log in.

Why you cannot immediately enter a password is unknown. That may be related to the unknown process that is autostarted and needs the keyring.

To avoid this dialog, either disable autologin or [set the password for the keyring to an empty string][1].

Take a look to your autostart applications to see which one may have caused this behaviour, and consider whether there is a need to autostart it,